# check if all inputs text are empty or not, and open colorbox if at least one are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

i am doing a form to send the quantity of products to an email address (the list is generated by php), the user put the quantity desired, and send it to an email, my form need open the colorbox window, only if at least one field is filled, if all are empty, and he click to send, i show the alert, i tryed it but, something is wrong. please check the fiddle;

http://jsfiddle.net/traoLe14/2/

HTML:

```
 <ul>
        <li class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="number" name="1" min="0" max="100" class="form-control product" value="1">Apple</li>
        <li class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="number" name="2" min="0" max="100" class="form-control product" value="0">Banana</li>
        <li class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="number" name="3" min="0" max="100" class="form-control product" value="0">Grape</li>
        <li class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="number" name="4" min="0" max="100" class="form-control product" value="0">Potato</li>
    </ul>
    <div> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default send_products">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> send list 
        </a>

    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(".send_products").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".product").each(function () {
        // print values on console
        console.log($(this).val());

        if ($(this).val() > 0) {
            $("send_products").addClass("inline", function () {
                $(".inline").colorbox({
                    inline: true,
                    height: "50%",
                    width: "50%",
                    innerWidth: 800,
                    innerHeight: "50%"
                });
            });
        } else {
            alert("no products added");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: in js, if 1 && 2 && 3 && 4 are empty alert, else submit

Comment: no, my php put an list with 180 inputs, this fiddle is only a example;

Comment: then use a loop? for 1 to 180 if empty alert and break, else increment name?

Comment: you are doing right . But you haven't code anywhere to open the colorbox .You just added the styles

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/traoLe14/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can first find the count of products with quantity > 0 with the below query

```
var length = $(".product").filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() > 0;
    }).length;
```

if length is > 0, do normal processing, else show alert

http://jsfiddle.net/mfarouk/traoLe14/3/

Comment: cool, i updated your code and it works for me now, but, one more thing...if i change the value again to "0" for all, he keep open the colorbox. http://jsfiddle.net/traoLe14/6/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try

`if($(this).val().length > 0)` instead of `if($(this).val() > 0)`

or maybe

`if(parseInt($(this).val()))` instead of `if($(this).val() > 0)`

If you check the `typeof $(this).val()` it will return string and then in if loop you are comparing it with 0. Maybe that's the issue.